# Номер на четырех человек или на четыре человека?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задумался: а как правильно сказать: "номер в гостинице на четырех человека" или "на четыре человека"?
По идее, как мне кажется, правильнее вообще сказать "для четыре человек" или "рассчитано на четырех человек".
Но хотелось бы все-таки знать, как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: номер на четырех человек, также: на одного человека, на двух/трех человек, но: на пять человек/пятерых человек. Также: рассчитано на четырех человек.

Здесь выражена категория одушевленности, поэтому форма В.п. (предлог НА) совпадает с формой Р.п.  Категорию одушевленности выражают числительные один, два, три, четыре, а также собирательные числительные. Остальные количественные числительные (пять и др.) не выражают одушевленность.

Для четырех человек - это Р.п. (предлог ДЛЯ), а не В.п.

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо и "на четыре человека"

Answer (score 0):

Да, допустимо также: номер на два человека.